# Understanding isomorphisms.

Tags: group-isomorphism

Can someone explain this solution to me?

The goal is to find an isomorphism from $ [\mathbb{Z}_6, \oplus_6]$ to $[\mathbb{Z}_7\setminus\{0\}, \otimes_7]$, where ${}\setminus\{0\}$ means "excluding 0".

There are 2 isomorphisms:

> $f(0) = 1, \quad f(1)=3, \quad f(2)=2, \quad f(3)=6, \quad f(4)=4, \quad f(5)=5$

and

> $f(0) = 1, \quad f(1)=5, \quad f(2)=4, \quad f(3)=6, \quad f(4)=2, \quad f(5)=3$

---

I don't understand part of the solution...

I know the generators for $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are {$1$, $5$}. Similarly, the generators for $\mathbb{Z}_7\backslash\{0\}$ are {$3$, $5$}.

To find the isomorphism, we're supposed to map corresponding powers of generators like so: $f(a^k)=b^k$, where $a$ is the generator for $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $b$ is the generator for $\mathbb{Z}_7 \backslash\{0\}$.

For the first isomorphism, we use $a=1$, $b=3$. For the second isomorphism, we use $a=1$, $b=5$. How am I supposed to know which $a$ and which $b$ to use? For example, how come there isn't an isomorphism that uses $a=5$, $b=3$? I know the $1$, $3$, and $5$ come from finding the generators, but I don't understand why the 2 isomorphisms use $a=1$, $b=3$ and $a=1$, $b=5$ in particular.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $1$ is mapped to $5,$ then what is $5$ mapped to? If $1$ is mapped to $3,$ then what is $5$ mapped to?

The kicker, here, is to pick a **consistent** generator, and decide what it gets mapped to. It doesn't actually matter *which* consistent generator gets picked, *so long as we remain consistent*. Based on the answer to the above questions, can you see why consistency is important?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! If 1->3, then that leaves 5->5. If 1->5, then that leaves 5->3.

Comment: Bingo! Also, I've just edited my answer. Please make sure you understand the update.